# Check status of a non-interrupt pin?

Tags: c, code-composer

So I am aware of how to check the status of a pin that has an interrupt enabled. This is done by using the following code:

```
    uint8_t status4;
    status4 = MAP_GPIO_getEnabledInterruptStatus(GPIO_PORT_P4);
```

What I am unsure of, and am unable to find an example of, is how to check the status of an input pin that does *not* have an interrupt enabled. I tried:

```
uint8_t status41
status41 = MAP_GPIO_getInputStatus(GPIO_PORT_P4)
```

and some other variations of that but have not had any success. Perhaps I just suck at googling this but does anyone know the syntax for what I am looking for?

Comment: What type of microcontroller is this for?

Comment: @duskwuff its for the MSP432. i believe i may have been premature on this post as i think i just found what im looking for. MAP_GPIO_getInputPinValue